# Can %%physloc%% be used as a row identifier or key for an on-the-fly query?

Tags: sql-server

Can `%%physloc%%` be used as a row identifier or key for an on-the-fly query? I know that `%%physloc%%` is not a reliable, long-term key because the physical location of a row may change, but that shouldn't matter for an ad-hoc query, right? `row_number()` works but `%%physloc%%` seems cleaner and faster.

Comment: Not a good idea. The physical location can change during query execution.